# Finding the area of a parallelogram given vertices

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vectors

> Find the area of the parallelogram with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,2)$, $(3,7)$, and $(2,5)$

I'm confused as to how I get started with this one.  Can you all provide me with hints to assist me?

Comment: I'd do it like this: $$\|(e_1 + 2e_2)\wedge (2e_1 + 5e_2)\| = \|(5-4)e_1\wedge e_2\| = 1$$ but perhaps you'd better use the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Geometric_meaning).

Comment: It's not impressive to use fancy looking techniques without explaining what you're doing.

Comment: @JacksonFitzsimmons I was hoping OP would ask me about it and then I'd have a chance to convert one more to geometric algebra.  Seems (s)he didn't care enough to, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cross product $AB X AC$ where

Vertices are $A(0,0) , B(1,2) , C(2,5),D(3,7) $

Vectors are $AB=(1 i,2 j) ,AC = (2 i,5 j). $

Answer (score 1):

I would start by drawing a picture, then if you're familiar with the cross product, recall what it's magnitude is equal to and go from there. If not, use trigonometry and other geometric techniques to break up the shape and evaluate the area piece by piece.

Answer (score 1):

Pick's Formula is a good thing to look up